# How to test testcase wise in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

Just like @Test (TestNG) in Selenium. Is there a way to test cases one by one and each test case not affecting the subsequent one in cypress?

Comment: Do you want to run tests (Test Suite .spec.js files) in a sequence of your choice ?

Comment: Yes i have multiple tests in one js file and  need to run them in a particular order

Answer (score 0):

The order of running .spec.js files can be defined within cypress.json.

For example:

```
{
    "testFiles": [
      "test_1.spec.js",
      "test_2.spec.js",
      "test_3.spec.js"
    ]    
}
```

If you are talking about the order of tests within a single .spec.js file, this is based on the order of your tests. You can choose to include only some of them by using the .only suffix on your it functions (in case you are using mocha). This will work for any number of functions.